# downloaded zip file corrupted

Tags: asp.net, zip, download

I'm using following code to download a zip file

```
protected void btnDownloadNow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { if (cblFiles.SelectedItem == null)
        {

            RegisterStartupScript("as","You must select one or more files to download.");

        }


        var downloadFileName = string.Format("Transmittal.zip", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH_mm_ss"));
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + downloadFileName);


        using (var zip = new ZipFile())
        {

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtZIPPassword.Text))
            {
                zip.Password = txtZIPPassword.Text;


                zip.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes128;
            }


            var readMeMessage = string.Format("Your ZIP file {0} contains the following files:{1}{1}", downloadFileName, Environment.NewLine);


            foreach (ListItem li in cblFiles.Items)
                if (li.Selected)
                {

                    readMeMessage += string.Concat("\t* ", li.Text, Environment.NewLine);

                    zip.AddFile(li.Value, "Your Files");
                }



            zip.AddEntry("README.txt", readMeMessage, Encoding.ASCII);


            zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);

        }
```

and i have the following javascript on the same page

```
function CheckAllPDF(value) {
            var elementRef = document.getElementById("<%= cblFiles.ClientID %>");
            var checkBoxArray = elementRef.getElementsByTagName('input');

            var checkBoxLabelArray = elementRef.getElementsByTagName('label');

            var checkedValues = '';

            for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxArray.length; i++) {

                var checkBoxRef = checkBoxArray[i];
                var checkBoxLabelRef = checkBoxLabelArray[i];
                var stringt = checkBoxLabelRef.innerHTML;
                var match = stringt.indexOf(".pdf");
                if (value == true) {
                    document.getElementById("<%=Checkbox1.ClientID %>").checked = false;
                    document.getElementById("<%=cc.ClientID %>").checked = false;
                    if (match != -1) {
                        checkBoxRef.checked = true;

                    }
                    else {
                        checkBoxRef.checked = false;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // checkBoxRef.checked = false;
                    if (match != -1) {

                        checkBoxRef.checked = false;
                        document.getElementById("<%=Checkbox1.ClientID %>").checked = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        // checkBoxRef.checked = true;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

my issue is the downloaded zip file is corrupted due to above javascript code.when i remove the javascript from the page zip file works fine.why this javascript cause such an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's ASP.NET code, not javascript.

I can't see all the necessary code but...

Your HTTP Response is getting all mangled up. Clear your HTTPResponseHeader before you send your file, flush afterwards, and make sure you end the HTTPContext Response

Something like this:

```
    //clear your headers
    Response.Clear();

    var downloadFileName = string.Format("Transmittal.zip", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH_mm_ss"));
    Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + downloadFileName);

    //Write (Send) your file
    Response.Write(  ... );
    Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```